# How to create an MS Project style web app

Tags: html, web-applications

As part of my personal project to understand web better, I would like to build a web app.

My idea is probably too complicated but has growing space in it. I would like to build a page that would act as a kind of 'MS Project' for finances. It would have similar structure to Project, on the left would be a list of tasks and on the right would be Gantt. Instead of displaying milestones and tasks, the web app would show a phased diagram of spend (with maybe some comparison between forecast and actual).

I can do all the server side stuff but I don't know where to begin with structuring the html to achieve this. 
Some of my getting started questions:

- How to achieve the synchronised vertical scrolling between the left and right pane?
- How to achieve the resizeable central diving bar that can be moved left and right?

I am now familiar with jQuery so I would want to use that to handle the java scripting

(turns out I'm not allowed to post images due to low reputation. here's a google [photos](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-yYVK62UPlJ4/U6MS-_Akk1I/AAAAAAAAATY/KsI-h8RvdTU/w1325-h750-no/IMAG0742+%25281%2529.jpg) link: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-yYVK62UPlJ4/U6MS-_Akk1I/AAAAAAAAATY/KsI-h8RvdTU/w1325-h750-no/IMAG0742+%25281%2529.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this example which uses jQuery for vertical sync'd scrolling and re-sizing.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/B3nLQ/) (I put the jquery script below and the HTML and CSS examples are in the fiddle)

```
  $(function(){ 
// set up initial; states pf panels
    $('#panel2').height("75px");
    $('#panel1').height($('#panel2').height());
    $('#panel1inner').height($('#panel1').height());
    $('#panel2inner').height($('#panel2').height());
    $('#panel1').width("49.5%");
    $('#panel1inner').width($('#panel1').width() + 17);
    $('#panel2').width("49.5%");
    $('#panel2inner').width($('#panel2').width() + 17);
//make panels resizable
    $('#panel1').resizable();
//link panels for scrolling
    $('.linked').scroll(function(){
        $('.linked').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());    
    })
//force panels to react to resizing
    $('#panel1').resize(function(){
       var newWidth = $('#container').width() - $('#panel1').width() - 3;
       $('#panel1inner').width($('#panel1').width() + 17);
       $('#panel1inner').height($('#panel1').height());
       $('#panel2').height($('#panel1').height());
       $('#panel2inner').height($('#panel2').height());
       $('#panel2').width(newWidth);
       $('#panel2inner').width(newWidth + 17);
    });
  });
```

Comment: That's really useful thank you. I am worried about using a lot of javascript to lay out the page? (I know that this doesn't really count as a lot of JS but the idea stands I think)

Comment: You could move all of the stuff under initial set up to the CSS - the only area this would get a bit difficult with would be the inner panels since they need the adjustment to "hide" their scroll-bars (+ 17px). Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/n7n6U/) with the panels set up in CSS (I kept the inner set-ups in jQuery because it makes things much easier, but they could easily be handled in CSS too)